# Disable Laravel CSRF Protection for /api routes when consuming API with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, csrf, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel backend, and React frontend. For development, React runs on `localhost:3000` and Laravel on `localhost:8080`, so I had to allow Cors.

I have set up Passport successfuly and am able to [Consume my API with JavaScript](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript).

But on every request, I have to include the X-CSRF-TOKEN to access protected API routes, which works, but for development I'd like to disable CSRF-Protection for the API.

I already tried to add the `/api` route to the `except` array in `VerifyCsrfToken` and removed the middleware from `Kernel.php` but this doesn't seem to change the fact that I still need to send the CSRF-Token.

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and use JavaScript fetch to make requests.

VerifyCsrfToken:

````
protected $except = [
    '/api/*'
];```
````

I commented out VerifyCsrfToken in the Kernel:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Example API route:

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    return response()->json(['success' => 'Hello!']);
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

How I try to access the API:

```
const checkStatus = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.ok) {
        return response;
    } else {
        const error = new Error(response.statusText);
        error.response = response;
        throw error;
    }
}

const parseJSON = res => res.text();

const Fetcher = {
    get: (ressource) => {
        return fetch(CONSTANTS.API_URL + ressource, {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                //'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
            },
            credentials: 'include'
        })
            .then(checkStatus)
            .then(parseJSON)
    },
    post: (ressource, data) => {
        return fetch(CONSTANTS.API_URL + ressource, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                //'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            body: data
        })
            .then(checkStatus)
            .then(parseJSON)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use the $except array you do not need to apply auth:api middleware to the route. But the route url should be something like "api/test"

Comment: Hm okay, but I still want the routes to be potected. I send the laravel_token with every request  so that I can access protected routes, but apparently that's not enough because I also have to sent the CSRF token which is not what I want.

Comment: Still you are telling laravel to not check for the CSRF token for "api/*" routes but your route is just "test" (it should be "api/test")

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, but without the X-CSRF-TOKEN in the request header, I get the error 401 unauthorized.

Comment: 401 is another error and its about auth token

Comment: Sorry for asking, but could you explain what you mean?
If I integrate my js code into the index.blade.php where the CSRF token is stored, and send this token with my request, then everyting is working fine.

It just doesn't work if I don't send that token...

Comment: CSRF Token protects you from cross-site request forgery. auth:api middleware instead (you use it) prevents users not authenticated to access some routes.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. But the documentation also states:

When using this method of authentication, the default Laravel JavaScript scaffolding instructs Axios to always send the X-CSRF-TOKEN and X-Requested-With headers. However, you should be sure to include your CSRF token in a HTML meta tag.

So as I understand it, this CSRF token is still required, if I want to use protected API routes as a logged in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to isolate the problem.
Remove auth:api middleware in the route:

```
Route::get('api/test', function() {
    return response()->json(['success' => 'Hello!']);
});
```

Note the url is "api/test" and not just "test" cause you defined the $except array like this:

```
protected $except = [
    '/api/*'
];
```

Do your call without passing CSRF token.

**EDITED**

From laravel documentation about auth:api middleware:

> Laravel includes an authentication guard that will automatically
>   validate API tokens on incoming requests. You only need to specify the
>   auth:api middleware on any route that requires a valid access token:

it means you have to pass API token to the routes under auth:api middleware, otherwise you get 401 error.

Comment: Without ```auth:api``` this works. 
I added the example of yours to my ````web.php``` routes, and I am able to access routes protected by ```->middleware(''auth')``` without the CSRF token. But If I addt this to my ```api.php```, I am not able to access protected routes. Without protection, it's works even with ```àuth.php``` routes.

Comment: if your route url is just "test" it should not work, can you confirm that?

Comment: In the ```api.php```, when I define ```Route::get('test')``` I have to access my route through ```localhost:8080/api/test```.

In the ```web.php``` I have to define ```Route::get('api/test')``` to access the route trough ```localhost:8080/api/test```

Comment: I know that you normally have to provide an API token. When I login, a laravel_token cookie is set, which is then sent to laravel with every request.

Comment: if you get 401 error, you dont send it to laravel. that error is explanatory

Comment: Thank you very much. JavaScript sends the laravel_token cookie when I run the JS app on the same port 8080, but not when I run it on 3000.

I haven't noticed that. I'll try to solve that first, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

under routes folder handle your api routes in api.php not in web.php